# function not running on load, but does on resize

Tags: jquery, resize, load

I have this which should run the function on `load` and also on `resize`:

```
$(window).resize(stuffForResizeAndReady);
$(document).ready(stuffForResizeAndReady);
```

however, the function does NOT run on load, but runs on resize, I did this to check:

```
if ($("#table").length) {
    alert("element found");
}
```

.. and it doesn't show the alert, however when resized, it does.

it seems as if the whole script is only activated on first resize, not before.

Comment: Can we maybe see the `stuffForResizeAndReady` function?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Its a couple of functions that change width. Heres the full script: http://pastebin.com/ErjEtTN6

Comment: You are attaching `$(document).ready()` from within `$(document).ready()`. That's not good.

Comment: There is no reason for $(document).ready(...) to not being executed on page load... The problem must be inside your stuffForResizeAndReady function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move these two lines outside your $(document).ready block:

```
$(window).resize(stuffForResizeAndReady);
$(document).ready(stuffForResizeAndReady);
```

Also move the definition of that `stuffForResizeAndReady` function (as suggested in a comment below).

Comment: ... and the definition of `stu..dy`